# How can I rename an app on my phone, and what are the consequences?

Tags: google-play-store, tasker, facebook-messenger, google-messages

Both Facebook and Google have apps called 'Messenger'. So, of course, when I use Google Now to open it, a la

> "Okay Google, open App Messenger"

it seems like it's usually not the one I want.

1) How can I rename an app on my phone (so that I could call `"open App FacebookMessenger"`, for instance, and disambiguate them)?

2) Would that break App Store updates or the connection between the Facebook app and it's Messenger app?

3) Is there another alternative I'm not thinking of? Like a Tasker-based voice solution or something? Google Now is the only problem I'm having with this namespace collision; a workaround for that would solve my problem.

Comment: It seems Google has solved the namespace collision issue by slightly re-naming their version. So this issue is solved in the particular case I asked about, but I'd still like the solution should this issue ever pop up again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are willing to install an app , you can try [Commandr for Google](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.RSen.Commandr), which let's you

- Integrate Tasker
- Launch an app under different name ( custom app name)

Not tried by me

Comment: As it turns out I already have that app installed, so this sounds like it'll be a solution. And it also avoids any unpleasant possible side-effects that might come from renaming an app.